# How to Condition Across Two SP Lists & Use Remaining Yes Items?

Tags: power-automate

I've created this flow that groups SP list rows by like-email and sends a notification including the value of those rows to each distinct email. It's been tested and works great.
[image]

I'm struggling with enhancing it to first evaluate with a condition that ItemNumber (List A) is equal to ItemNumber (List B), the where True, perform the remainder of the already tested steps. Ultimately, I want everything that already works to be performed on a smaller list items that only exist on both lists.

I'm facing two issues:

#1 - PowerAutomate isn't letting me nest the variable actions within the Yes condition, stating that they have to be top level.

#2 - I've found that I can have all of the steps in the screenshot besides the existing Apply to Each above the condition, but PowerAutomate adds multiple nested Apply to Each's when I try that and the outcome is multiple emails with non-evaluated quantities of items returns.
[image]

I think I simply have the order of actions wrong, but I cannot find the right order to get this done. Does anyone have advice or a solution?